# LetterHead in Apex

Tags: apex, email-template, singleemailmessage

Is it possible to access [LetterHead](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=admin_brandtemplates.htm&siteLang=en_US) in apex.I need to put the letter head in sethtmlbody method.How to access LetterHead.

**UPDATED**

Here the bt.value is displaying blank when contact is receiving an email but when I debug the value of **bt.value** it is showing some html code in it

```
         BrandTemplate bt = [select id,Value from BrandTemplate where name='Standard Letterhead' limit 1]; 
         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
         String[] toAddresses = new String[] {Contact_Email__c}; 
         mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
         mail.setSenderDisplayName('Support');
         mail.setSubject('Invoice');
         mail.setBccSender(false); 
         mail.setUseSignature(false);
         String messageBody = '<html>'+ bt.Value + '<body>'+ '<p>Dear '+ o.Contact__r.Name + ': </p>'+'Some TEXT'
         mail.setHtmlBody(messageBody)          
         Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Comment: please look at the update answer

Comment: is there a reason why you are avoiding template? are you trying to construct your template dynamically? I am not seeing the letter head images show up on my email too. I tried to make the images available publicly, loaded into a document. No luck yet!!!

Comment: yes I am trying to construct template dynamically.

Comment: @rao Any luck on this.

Comment: @rao I have uploaded header and  footer of LetterHead to Documents and made it accessible externally and used it in trigger and it works.Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_brandtemplate.htm

```
BrandTemplate bt = [select id from BrandTemplate where name='Blank' limit 1];
```

Update:

A letter head goes in conjunction with HTML Email template. So to access letterhead from email template query

```
emailtemplate et = [select BrandTemplateId from emailtemplate where brandtemplateId.name='Blank' limit 1];
system.debug('## Email template's letter head :'+ et.brandtemplateId);
```

To answer the second part of your question 
*I need to put the letter head in sethtmlbody method.How to access LetterHead.*

AFAIK you cannot do this when you try to use together

```
mail.sethtmlbody();
mail.settemplateid();
```

you will get get an error

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: INVALID_FIELD_WHEN_USING_TEMPLATE, When a template is
>   specified the plain text body, html body, subject and charset may not
>   be specified : []

Comment: welcome back Rao

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thanks, too busy at work have be on and off :)

Comment: As long as you're not using merge fields in the email template, you can probably bring your BrandTemplate and EmailTemplate together in code using just sethtmlbody() and String.replace() to shove the EmailTemplate into the correct location in the BrandTemplate.

Comment: BrandTemplate bt = [select id,Value from BrandTemplate where name='Standard Letterhead' limit 1];                                                       String messageBody = '<html>'+ bt.Value + '<body>'+ '<p>Dear '+ o.Contact__r.Name + ': </p>';

Comment: Here the bt.value is displaying blank when contact is receiving an email but when I debug the value of bt.value it is showing some html code in it

Comment: @sf.dev can you paste your updated code on the original question

Comment: @rao updated code